# Facebook Graph API: Getting information on each checkin time from a location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

Is there a way to get specific information about each checkin at a location via the Facebook Graph API.  For instance, if location A has 341 total checkins, can I query FB for the time of each of those checkins?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the Graph API with a GET of `/${PAGE_ID}/checkins` but it looks like this will return only the user's checkins (if she's granted `user_checkins`) & her friends' checkins (if she's granted `friends_checkins`).

If you're the Page's owner you might be able to see more; I haven't tested this.